# python dynamic values to relativedelta function

Tags: python, python-datetime, relativedelta, python-relativedelta

Im trying to provide dynamic value to relativedelta function, i.e `relativedelta(days=1)` i would like to assign dynamic function value `days`, `months`, `years` to the function. Consider my situation as follows.
I will get list dynamicaly as follows:

```py
Ex: 1

list = ['today', 'minus', '1', 'days']

Ex: 2

list = ['today', 'plus', '1', 'year']

Ex: 3

list = ['today', 'plus', '1', 'months']
```

I wrote my code to handle the calculation

```py
import operator
from datetime import datetime
from datetime import date
from dateutil.relativedelta import relativedelta

operations = {
        'plus': operator.add,
        'minus': operator.sub,
    }
today = date.today()
new_date = self.operations['plus'](today, relativedelta(days=1))

# the above is some thing like [today + relativedelta(days=1)]
```

What I'm trying to do is like `operations` I would like to assign `days`, `months`, `years` to the `relativedelta()` function, but I couldn't able to do it. Any suggested way to do it?

Answer (score 1):

Found a way to do it!

We can use the `**expression` call syntax to pass in a dictionary to a function instead, it'll be expanded into keyword arguments (which your `**kwargs` function parameter will capture again):

```
attributes = {'days': 1}
relativedelta(**attributes)
```